# Why does angular's ng-disabled works with bootstrap's btn class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an anchor tag on which, ng-disabled directive doesn't work at all.
It works on buttons but as soon as I add the Bootstrap's btn class to the anchor tag, Angular's ng-disabled starts working fine!

How is this working ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`ngDisabled` only works for elements that respond to the `disabled` attribute (inputs, textareas, radio buttons, button tags... etc.). In Bootstrap, you have to add the "disabled" class to your btn elements. That would look like this:

```
<div class="btn btn-default disabled">I'm a button!</div>
```

To do this in angular, define a variable in your directive/controller like so:

```
$scope.disableButtons = true;
```

Then use the angular `ngClass` to dynamically add the class based on the variable like so:

```
<div class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'disabled': disableButtons}" ng-click="doSomething()">I'm a button!</div>
```

Every time you change the `disableButtons` variable within your scope, the button will appear to be disabled or enabled in the view depending on the value.

**NOTE:** Adding the disabled class to btn elements does not prevent JS click events from occuring. In order to do this, you have to write a hook in your `doSomething()` function like so:

```
$scope.doSomething = function() {
  if($scope.disableButtons) {
    return;
  }
  // Else, really do something
}
```

**EDIT:** It appears I didn't really answer the question. The real answer (I believe) is that `disabled` only works for `.btn` elements as well as links `<a><a/>` and list `<li><li/>` elements (... and probably a few more) because that's what Bootstrap defines it should work on. Here's the source from Bootstrap for `btn` elements:

```
.btn.disabled, .btn[disabled], fieldset[disabled] .btn {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: .65;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

To get this working for anchor tags, you're going to have to write your own CSS replicating this, or even better, if you're using SASS to do something like `@extend` the styles.

Comment: I think the OP is asking why it _is_ working after adding the `btn` class.  Not how to fix it.

Comment: so ng-disabled just adds disabled class ?

Comment: `ngDisabled` adds the disabled attribute... which it also looks like Bootstrap picks up from the source that I provided, which I was unaware of. That would explain why your anchor tag is getting disabled when you add the `ng-disabled` attribute

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I did. It's bit of a hack but works

in css

```
a[data-disabled=true] {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: .65;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

in html

```
<a data-disabled="{{some boolean expersion}}" href="#2">Test</a>
```

Comment: Look at the accepted answer. It answers the question properly and helps one understand what to do. What additional is your hackish answer adding here ?