# AngularJS - ng-disabled not working for Anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using ng-disabled, I like it. It's working good for me for input and buttons. For anchor tag not working. How can I fix?

`HTML code`

```
<a ng-disabled="addInviteesDisabled()">Add</a>
```

`JS code`

```
  $scope.addInviteesDisabled = function() {
      return $scope.event.status === APP_CONSTANTS.STATUSES.PENDING_APPROVAL;
  };
```

Comment: You should use ng-show instead.

Comment: I should show anchor tag in disabled state @Vineet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955667/disabled-href-tag

Comment: Use button instead achor tag

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There is no disabled attribute for hyperlinks.
You can do this:

```
.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

<a ng-click="disabled()" ng-class="{disabled: addInviteesDisabled()}">Add</a>

$scope.disabled = function() {
  if($scope.addInviteesDisabled) { return false;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JsIsAwesome. I changed as
`.disabled {
  cursor: default;
  opacity: .5;
}`

Comment: @Donthamsettivbhadrarao +1 for the `opacity: .5` thanks. :D

Comment: Don't forget the quotes around the class name in the ng-class! ;)

Comment: You don't have to if this is one word, you need this for example for 'class-name'

Comment: Though the solution works, but user can go and remove the cursor:not-enabled css from console. What are your thoughts ?

Comment: At least in ui-router, the link remains clickable while the cursor shows disabled, I'd say that makes the link not disabled.

Comment: Also, you can just tab over to the link and press enter

Answer (score 26):

You could create a `linkDisabled` css class, and apply it to your anchor:

```
<style>

.linkDisabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: grey;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Might want to be careful with this one since as of June 2016 the `pointer-event` rule is only supported in ie 11+.  All other browsers are reasonably safe. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: also even if this solution is applied, the link can be clicked on with enter

Comment: Wrong. The cursor have not effect there with the pointer-events none

Answer (score 12):

You can do this through CSS, no fancy directives needed. Just use ng-class to apply a class sort of like this:

ng-class:

```
ng-class="{disabledLink: disabledFunction()}"
```

css:

```
.disabledLink {
    color: #ccc;
    pointer-events:none;

}
```

full credit to-

https://css-tricks.com/pointer-events-current-nav/

Answer (score 7):

You can't disable anchor tag using `ng-disabled`.

Form control has disabled property but anchor tag has no disable property.

Check [Why does angular's ng-disabled works with bootstrap's btn class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23408998/4161269)

Answer (score 2):

Yes buddy we can disable the anchor tag, lets see what need to do that. Anchor is clickable , first we nedd to disable the click   , we can do that by pointer-events: none;  and then to show the use it's disabled we can change the color on which we have to disable it like color: #95979A;. Still we need to understand whats happening here, adding the above will not disable the click event of anchor tag. To stop that we need to add ng-disabled which we add the attribute event as disabeld=disabled, We need to catch that using a[disabled].

So final Code :
**a[disabled] {pointer-events: none;color: #95979A;}**
 will disable the click event of the anchor tag.

Hope this helped.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can user fieldset for enable disable a link.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.iagree"> I Agree
      <fieldset ng-disabled="!vm.iagree">
               <a class="btn btn-primary grey" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="vm.Submit()">Submit</a>
      </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not disable anchor tag directly.You can do something this:

Assign two property in controller

```
public bool btndisabled { get; set; }
public string href { get; set; }
```

And use it for controller side code :

```
if (auction.btndisabled== true)
            {
                auction.href = "javaScript:void(0);";
            }
            else
            {
                auction.href = "/Auction/Index?id=" + auction.Auction_ID;
            }
```

In your view :

```
<a href="{{item.href}}"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="item.btndisabled" value="Update"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

When `ng-Disabled` evaluated to `true`, sets the `disabled` attribute on the element which is generally an input, or other form control. `<a>` tags don't have `disabled` attributes so it will never be set. Try setting the `ng-disabled` on your link to `true` and you will see for yourself.

Maybe this will help: [ng-disabled And Anchor Tags Oh Noes!](http://onehungrymind.com/quick-note-ng-disabled-and-anchor-tags-oh-noes/)

Comment: Yes I referred this tutorial, before asking this question @adamjld. But I should use anchor instead of button.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add the disabled condition into the function of the anchor. Thus, the functions only perform when the disabled condition is checked and passed.

```
$scope.next_kh_resource = function(){
    if ($scope.selected_kh_index < ($scope.selected_step.step_kh_resources.length -1)){
        var next = $scope.selected_kh_index + 1;
        $scope.selected_kh_index = $scope.selected_kh_index +1;
        $scope.selected_kh_resource = $scope.selected_step.step_kh_resources[next];
    }
}
$scope.prev_kh_resource = function(){
    if ($scope.selected_kh_index > 0){
        var prev = $scope.selected_kh_index -1;
        $scope.selected_kh_index = prev;
        $scope.selected_kh_resource = $scope.selected_step.step_kh_resources[prev];
    }

}
```

In the example above, I disabled the pagination anchors next and prev by inserting the disabled condition into the functions. **The users are smart.** They will soon learn that its the end page and they can click next but nothing will happen

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem doing a navigation buttons, this workaround was a good solution for my project!

```
<a href="{{nextItem ? '/the-link/i-want-to-use' : '#'}}" ng-class="{'iamDisabled':!nextItem}">Some link text</a>
```

Basically, there are two buttons (made with links tags) one for next and other for previous. there are two `$scope` variables, `nextItem` and `prevItem` , one for each button. So if there is no next (or previous) the  tag will be styled properly (so you see its disabled).

When `nextItem` is not null, the `href` will be rendered to `href="/the-link/i-want-to-use"` and when is null, href will be `href="#"`.

Answer (score 0):

No disabled attribute in anchor tag. Used "disabled" class for anchor tag.

```
$scope.data = {name:dinesh}
<a ng-click="get_data()" ng-class="{disabled: data}">Add</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-href` to disable event

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25386870)

Comment: I think anchor tags are not clickable without href, thats why I told. After href gave that disabled attr will work

Answer (score 0):

There is no disabled attribute for hyperlinks in Angular JS. So you can do follows:

html

```
<a ng-click="disabled()" ng-class="{disabled: isLinkDisabled}">LINK TO Disable</a>
```

app.js

```
$scope.disabled = function() {
        $scope.isLinkDisabled = true;
    }
```

CSS

```
.disable{
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Use `a-disabled` instead of `ng-disabled`

```
  <a a-disabled="addInviteesDisabled()">Add</a>
```

Comment: Not working `a-disabled` Umesh Kolapkar. What is this `a-disabled`? Please give any reference.

Comment: its custom directive. Checkout this link http://plnkr.co/edit/GkP1ukju4FWgBeprBLwj?p=preview

Comment: You should update your answer to inform people that they should include the custom directive before pasting code for it. Lotta people are in copy-pasta mode when they are searching for a working solution. ;)