# disabling a link in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have link which should be disabled when checkbox in not selected and it would be enabled when checkBox is selected

```
 <div class="col-md-3" >
     <span class="linkLayout">
          <a ng-click="open(calDay.dayNum)" >Add timeblock</a>
     </span>
</div>
```

and checkboxes are

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label class="i-checks">
       <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="calendar.workingDays"  
        checklist-value="calDay.dayNum" ng-change="selectDay(calDay.dayNum)" ><i></i>{{calDay.dayName}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create any Fiddle with your angular js code.

Comment: Another way is to create a button and make it look like a link, it's easy with bootstrap, then you can use ng-disabled.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** since my answer wasn't enough to put you on the right track, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/vedgurLq/) showing how one could solve such a problem.

In this example I've switched to a `button` element to allow the usage of `ng-disabled`, but the principle works on the anchor method as well (also you could easily style the button to look like a link respectively).

---

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30479306/4068027) on disabling links.

Then you can `ng-bind` the value of the checkbox to a variable and bind the `ng-class` of the link to that variable as well - no need for any function calls.

Comment: i think you are saying ryt but be more specific

Comment: somewhat along the lines of `<a ng-class="{disabled: ctrl.disabled}">` and `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.disabled">`

Comment: and in the click function you'll have to check on disabled, somewhat like `function open(param) { if(!disabled) { // do stuff } }`

Comment: it is disabling only it should also be enable when i clicked on checkbox so how to enable

Comment: There is no need to enable the checkbox. It's all based on conditional logic and two-way data binding. As soon as the value of the checkbox changes, the variable is updated whereon the conditional class is updated. If you can't observe that behaviour please provide a fiddle. (also I'd highly advise you to read through some basic AngularJs tutorials)

Comment: now you can see there is value sunday,monday,......etc.but and there is also add time block .firsly i Add time block link  should be disabled when checkbox is not checked but it should be enable when specific checkbox is checked

Comment: You don't have to copy lots of code. Take a look at [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), sometimes it's easier to just start from scratch and put together everything to demonstrate the problem (that's what I did in my fiddle). Check out the edit to my answer.

Comment: you have wrote what i have needed ...once again thanks for your help ..i have changed in my project according to you and it is working

Answer (score 0):

Don't put any Condition Expression in Template.
Do it at the Controller.

`$scope.open = function(daynum) {
    if (daynum) {
       //code of function
    }
}`