# Anchor tag disable using ng-class and a condition

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I've a table displayed which has `count` coulmn & this `count` has `<a>` tag with href to a page.
I want to show link for all `count > 0`  and disable for `count=0`.

I've tried [AngularJS - ng-disabled not working for Anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479105/angularjs-ng-disabled-not-working-for-anchor-tag[LINK]) and came to know that using `ng-disabled` is of no use.

Using `ng-class` is gonna help, but I'm not able to specify condition in `ng-class`.

P.S. I want `cursor:not-allowed` to be written in `ng-class` itself. Can't change CSS

***Here's my HTML Code***

```
<tr ng-repeat="service in services">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{service.serviceName}}</td>
    <td><a href="#/info/{{service.id}}">{{service.numberOfScenarios}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

`numberOfScenarios` displays `count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show basic information, use `ng-show`.

If you want to apply any classes use `ng-class`. The `cursor:not-allowed` is CSS, if you have it on a class already apply it by `ng-class="{'yourclassname':angular-condition}"`

You could also use something like this:

```
<td>
    <a ng-href="#/info/{{service.id}}" ng-show="service.numberOfScenarios > 0"><span ng-bind="service.numberOfScenarios></span></a>
</td>
```

The link won't show for `service.numberOfScenarios === 0`. There should be no need to add the CSS then.

**Update:**

```
<td>
    <a ng-href="#/info/{{service.id}}" ng-show="service.numberOfScenarios > 0">
        <span ng-bind="service.numberOfScenarios"></span>
    </a>
    <span ng-show="service.numberOfScenarios === 0" ng-bind="service.numberOfScenarios" style="cursor:not-allowed;"></span>
</td>
```

Comment: It's ok. But I want to show `0` without any link on it. `count` value is to be shown

Comment: This works too.. Thanks!!!

Above @nitz code also worked but hardcoding wasn't which I was looking for.

Comment: I was getting a cross symbol when hovered over 0.. so used @nitz class="notAllowedClass" and worked fine.

Comment: Yeah sure, you can add any inline CSS you want or just add a class and apply CSS rules there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as devjsp suggest to hide link.

Or you can use something like this.

```
<a ng-href="count > 0 ? '#/info/{{service.id}}' : ''">Google</a>
```

**Updated:**

```
<span ng-show="count > 0">
    <a href="#/info/{{service.id}}">Link</a>
</span>
<span ng-show="count === 0" class="notAllowedClass">
    0 <!-- As you suggested in another answer that you want to show 0 count -->
</span>
```

Comment: For `count=0` link will still be there.. I dont want the link itself.

Comment: Yeah Works!! Thanks..
I liked the way @devjsp did coz he didn't hardcoded the 0 in HTML.

But anyways both works ...