# Microsoft Edge - Disabled link is clickable

Tags: css, angularjs, microsoft-edge, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have an angular anchor tag in my page, and when it is disable it's still clickable in the Microsoft Edge browser.

```
<a ng-disabled="true" ng-click="Click()">Link</a>


a[disabled] {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - ng-disabled not working for Anchor tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479105/angularjs-ng-disabled-not-working-for-anchor-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

<a ng-click="disabled()" ng-class="{disabled: addInviteesDisabled()}">Link</a>

$scope.disabled = function() {
  //your display logic goes here should return true/false
}
```