# Angular JS - disable anchor link in IE without using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want angularjs solution for this problem.

I am working in angular JS and I am disabling anchor link using css style.
This works fine with Chrome and Firefox but not with IE. I am able to click the link even if it is shown as grayed out. Jquery is not allowed . How to achieve disabled anchor link for IE without jquery?

```
**css style**

a.offline {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["pointer-events: none" does not work in IE9 and IE10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441810/pointer-events-none-does-not-work-in-ie9-and-ie10)

Comment: I want angular solution not Jquery or plain javascript . This is not duplicate please

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985112/angular2-what-is-the-correct-way-to-disable-an-anchor-element)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479105/angularjs-ng-disabled-not-working-for-anchor-tag