# angularjs conditional render tags with the same content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I encountered a problem while working with AngularJS as below

```
<div ng-switch='isTrue'>
  <div ng-switch-when='true' class='active-style' data-id='1'>Content</div>
  <div ng-switch-when='false' class='disabled-style' data-id='2'>Content</div>
</div>
```

Given this example, is it possible to not duplicate the `Content` text? i.e. can AngularJS renders the tags independently?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to disable your anchor tag right?
Try solution from this question:
[AngularJS - ng-disabled not working for Anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479105/angularjs-ng-disabled-not-working-for-anchor-tag)

Comment: Have you heard about flagging posts in stackoverflow?

Comment: @un-lucky, thanks, heard about it did not use it.

Comment: it's not the disabled anchor that I'm aiming for, it's just happen to be anchor tag.

So if there is like 2 different divs that has different properties, but with the same content, is there a way to not duplicate the contents and render the tags independently

Comment: I dont think anyone will need to do this thing, that divs that have same content with two different properties. @lightbringer give your exact problem here, why would u need to do this way?