# Why ng-disabled not work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to disable `<a>` with ng-disabled but not work and I put disabled but it does not work too. My HTML like this

```
<div class="action-engine">
    <a on-hold="engine()" class="btn3d default actived" ng-disabled="button_clicked">
        <div class="back-overlay"></div>
        <div class="inner-circle">
             <div class="inner-icon"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

and I include in JS like this **`$scope.button_clicked = true;`**. I don't know it still can press. If you have some idea to solve my problem it helpful. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479105/angularjs-ng-disabled-not-working-for-anchor-tag

Answer (score 0):

Button should be used for ng-disabled:-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

$scope.button_clicked = true;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div class="action-engine">
      <button on-hold="engine()" class="btn3d default actived" ng-disabled="button_clicked">
        <div class="back-overlay"></div>
        <div class="inner-circle">
             <div class="inner-icon">Link</div>
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If we place a button we would loose all the html inside the a tag. @

Comment: You mean we can not use html inside button tag?

Comment: I was try button but still cannot be disabled

Comment: There must be some other error in your code, share your controller code as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="action-engine">
    <a on-hold="engine()" class="btn3d default actived" ng-disabled="button_clicked">
        <div class="back-overlay"></div>
        <div class="inner-circle">
             <div class="inner-icon"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The a tag in html does not get disabled. 
Use below class using

```
ng-class="{'avoid-clicks' : button_clicked }"

.avoid-clicks {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: it still not work

Comment: have you included the css class, and placed the ng-class attribute