# Need to sort the list in ascending order based on date object which is coming from JSON

Tags: angularjs

I want to sort the list based on  date in ascending order.I am getting date object from JSON.I am using orderBy filter  but its not working.

My code is given below.

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                <li ng-repeat="list in a.b.c| orderBy:'Date'">
                                    <div class="hoverBackground">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-disabled="(list[0].price * 1 == 0)" >{{list.Name}} </a>

                                    </div>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

In controller,
$scope.a.b.c=[];

Comment: Can we have your code in fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `disabled` attribute [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408683/why-does-angulars-ng-disabled-works-with-bootstraps-btn-class#answer-23408998) with `li` and `a` elements, so there is no point in using `ng-disabled`. You have to do this by yourself by adding a `disabled` class and handle it in css.

HTML:

```
 <li ng-repeat="" ng-class="{'disabled':item.price == 0}"><a></a></li>
```

Set background color for disabled `li`s

```
.disabled .hoverBackground{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Change background color on hover only for not disabled `li`s:

```
li:not(.disabled) .hoverBackground:hover {
    background-color: //yourHoverColor
}
```

Comment: I have applied ng-disabled on anchor tag and its working fine.

Comment: it shouldnt^^...anyway this should handle the li's background color properly.

Comment: Hey,i implemented in your way.Removed ng-disabled and tried your way.But still the color appears on hover for disabled list.So,i guess that's because of my structure.Due to some constraint,i had to take anchor tag in a div and given background color for the div.So,is it possible to achieve in your way now without changing my structure.

Comment: `background-color: none` won't override any color that is set by another css class because it isn't a valid value for `background-color`

Comment: @user2138675 why dont you put the exact structure in your question? With 'something like that' you will only get answers that work for something like that...

Answer (score 0):

`none` isn't a valid color for background-color. You can use transparent or inherit or `background: none;` depending on what you want.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{name:'a',price: 0}, {name:'b', price:1}];
});
```

```css
.list-item:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.no-background:hover {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myController'>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" class="list-item" ng-class="{'no-background': !item.price}">{{item.name}} {{item.price}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```